# Connection refused to GCP LoadBalancer in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

When I create a deployment and a service in a Kubernetes Engine in GCP I get connection refused for no apparent reason.

The service creates a Load Balancer in GCP and all corresponding firewall rules are in place (allows traffic to port 80 from `0.0.0.0/0`). The underlying service is running fine, when I `kubectl exec` into the pod and `curl localhost:8000/` I get the correct response.

This deployment setting used to work just fine for other images, but yesterday and today I keep getting

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.x.x.x port 80: Connection refused
```

What could be the issue? I tried deleting and recreating the service multiple times, with no luck.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: app 
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: gcr.io/myproject/my-app:0.0.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This turned out to be a dumb mistake on my part. The gunicorn server was using a bind to `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`, so it wasn't accessible from outside of the pod, but worked when I `exec`-ed into the pod.

The fix in my case was changing the entrypoint of the Dockerfile to

```
CMD [ "gunicorn", "server:app", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "-w", "3" ]
```

rebuilding the image and updating the deployment.

Comment: Hey @robert-lacok ! Can you give a bit more detail on how you solved the problem? Did you have to redeploy? Only edit a configuration?

Comment: You are a godsend, after slogging through endless tutorials that just didn't work I found that my webapp was doing the same thing, and it's working now --___--`

Comment: Saved me from my dumb mistake too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the service binding to your pod? What does "kubectl describe svc my-app" say?

Make sure it transfers through to your pod on the correct port?  You can also try, assuming you're using an instance on GCP, to curl the IP and port of the pod and make sure it's responding as it should?

ie, kubectl get pods -o wide, will tell you the IP of the pod

does curl ipofpod:8000 work?

Comment: It seems to be binding fine, the IP of the pod is listed among endpoints. When I curl ipofpod:port I get the same error, connection refused, both from within a GKE node or a VM in the same network.

Comment: Can you ping the pod?

Comment: Wondering if you have any firewall rules on your VM?